# Get the ID of a Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to get the id of this user foreign key.

```
class Report(models.Model):

    user=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='report_user')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_username()
```

I want to get the user id in the same class. This doesn't seem to work.

```
def cor_report(self):

        return Test.objects.get(id=user_id)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
def cor_report(self):
    return Test.objects.get(id=self.user.id)
```

Comment: It works! Thanks :)  Sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer :/